# upgrade engine MySQL Community from version 5.7 to 8.0 on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-aurora

i got email from AWS like this

> You are receiving this message because you have one or more Amazon RDS for MySQL DB instances running major version 5.7 that require your attention. The MySQL community has deprecated MySQL 5.7 in October, 2023, and it will not receive any security patches after October, 2023. Therefore, Amazon RDS will end standard support of MySQL major version 5.7 on February 29, 2024.
>
> We recommend that you take action and upgrade your Amazon RDS for MySQL databases (DB) running major version 5.7 to major version 8.0 before end of standard support in February, 2024. Amazon RDS for MySQL 8.0 offers new query functionality, enhancements for better performance, reliability, security and manageability. To learn more about the benefits of MySQL 8.0, refer to ‘Amazon RDS for MySQL 8.0 Announcement’.

In addition to my MySQL Community DB engine that requires an upgrade, I also have a DB using the Aurora MySQL engine with version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.2. Do I need to upgrade this as well?

Comment: I think the question title is misleading as your real question is about aurora, not about rds

Answer (score 0):

See this link: [AWS Aurora Versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.VersionPolicy.html)

This advises that Aurora MySQL 2 standard support ends on 31 Oct 2024.
So if you do not want to pay the higher cost of extended support for your Aurora RDS, it is recommended to get upgraded to Aurora 3 before the standard support end date.

[Upgrading to Aurora MySQL version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.mysql80-upgrade-procedure.html)

Amazon Aurora reuses code and maintains compatibility with the underlying MySQL and PostgreSQL DB engines. However, Aurora has its own version numbers, release cycle, time line for version deprecation, and so on.